# How to ouput data to a file in CasperJS?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm using CasperJS for a data scraping project I'm working on. I've got it up and running and my initial scripts are starting to work. I have it outputting the table I need to the console. Now I need to figure out how to get it to put the data I need into a file, so that I may import it into my eCommerce management software. Does anyone have any tips on how to get it to spit out the data into a file, preferably CSV or something I can open with Excel.

The working code I've got looks like this so far:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
casper.start('http://www.123FAKE.com/');
casper.then(function(){
    this.thenOpen('http://www.123FAKE.com/products/?partNumber=1131180961', function(){
        this.echo(this.getHTML('table.partFitmentTable', true));
    });
});

casper.run();
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

A CSV file is a very simple text file. You can build the file text as a string in the intended format and simply write the string into a file using the [fs module](http://phantomjs.org/api/fs/).

For that you will probably need to scrape the table into an appropriate form. You can only access the DOM directly from `casper.evaluate()` which is the sandboxed page context.

```
var csv = casper.evaluate(function(){
    var trList = document.querySelectorAll("table.partFitmentTable tr");
    return [].map.call(trList, function(tr){
        return [].map.call(tr.querySelectorAll("td"), function(td){
            td.innerHTML; // some representation of the cell
        }).join(",");
    }).join("\n");
});
var fs = require("fs");
fs.write("data.csv", csv);
```